# MongoDb: Getting $avg in aggregate for complex data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get an average rating in my Mongo aggregate and am having trouble accessing the nested array. I've gotten my aggregation to give the following array. I'm trying to have city_reviews return an array of averages.

```
[ 
  {
    "_id": "Dallas",
    "city_reviews": [
           //arrays of restaurant objects that include the rating
           //I would like to get an average of the rating in each review, so these arrays will be numbers (averages)
           [ {
              "_id": "5b7ead6d106f0553d8807276",
              "created": "2018-08-23T12:41:29.791Z",
              "text": "Crackin good place. ",
              "rating": 4,
              "store": "5b7d67d5356114089909e58d",
              "author": "5b7d675e356114089909e58b",
              "__v": 0
              }, {review2}, {review3}]
           [{review1}, {review2}, {review3}],
           [{review1}. {review2}],
           [{review1}, {review2}, {review3}, {review4}],
           []
      ]

   },
  {
    "_id": "Houston",
    "city_reviews": [
           // arrays of restaurants 
           [{review1}, {review2}, {review3}],
           [{review1}, {review2}, {review3}],
           [{review1}, {review2}, {review3}, {review4}],
           [],
           []
      ]
  }

]
```

I would like to do an aggregation on this that returns an array of averages within the city_reviews, like this:

```
{
    "_id": "Dallas",
    "city_reviews": [
           // arrays of rating averages
           [4.7],
           [4.3],
           [3.4],
           [],
           []
      ]
  }
```

Here's what I've tried. It's giving me back averageRating of null, because $city_reviews is an array of object and I'm not telling it to go deep enough to capture the rating key.

```
return this.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: 'reviews', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'store', as: 
      'reviews' }},
    {$group: {_id: '$city', city_reviews: { $push : '$reviews'}}},
    { $project: {
       averageRating: { $avg: '$city_reviews'}
    }}
 ])
```

Is there a way to work with this line so I can return arrays of averages instead of the full review objects.

```
averageRating: { $avg: '$city_reviews'}
```

EDIT: Was asked for entire pipeline.

```
return this.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: 'reviews', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'store', as: 'reviews' }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$city', 
        city_reviews: { $push : '$reviews'}}
    },
    { $project: {
        photo: '$$ROOT.photo',
        name: '$$ROOT.name',
        reviews: '$$ROOT.reviews',
        slug: '$$ROOT.slug',
        city: '$$ROOT.city',
        "averageRatingIndex":{
            "$map":{
            "input":"$city_reviews",
            "in":[{"$avg":"$$this.rating"}]
            }
        },
     }
    },
    { $sort: { averageRating: -1 }},
    { $limit: 5 }
])
```

My first query was to connect two models together:

```
{ $lookup: { from: 'reviews', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'store', as: 'reviews' }},
```

Which resulted in this:

```
[ {
    "_id": "5b7d67d5356114089909e58d",
    "location": {},
    "tags": [],
    "created": "2018-08-22T13:23:23.224Z",
    "name": "Lucia",
    "description": "Great name",
    "city": "Dallas",
    "photo": "ab64b3e7-6207-41d8-a670-94315e4b23af.jpeg",
    "author": "5b7d675e356114089909e58b",
    "slug": "lucia",
    "__v": 0,
    "reviews": []
  },
  {..more object like above}
]
```

Then, I grouped them like this:

```
{$group: {
     _id: '$city', 
     city_reviews: { $push : '$reviews'}}
 }
```

This returned what my original question is about. Essentially, I just want to have a total average rating for each city. My accepted answer does answer my original question. I'm getting back this:

```
{
  "_id": "Dallas",
  "averageRatingIndex": [
     [ 4.2 ],
     [ 3.6666666666666665 ],
     [ null ],
     [ 3.2 ],
     [ 5 ],
     [ null ]
   ]
}
```

I've tried to use the $avg operator on this to return one, final average that I can display for each city, but I'm having trouble.

Comment: If you give us the raw source data we might come up with an optimized version of your entire pipeline.

Comment: Edited with entire pipeline and resulting data. I hope this shows what I've done. I would really appreciate some suggestions or help on how to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` to with `$avg` to output avg.

```
{"$project":{
  "averageRating":{
     "$map":{
      "input":"$city_reviews",
      "in":[{"$avg":"$$this.rating"}]
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: Bwaha! Thank you! I'll have to read into $map for the future.

Comment: Thanks for answering my initial question. I've edited the post to reflect what I'm trying to do, as I'm still having trouble. I'd appreciate another look!

Comment: Yw. If you just need one avg you can use `{"$project":{
  "averageRatingIndex":{"$avg":{
     "$map":{
      "input":"$city_reviews",
      "in":{"$avg":"$$this.rating"}
    }
  }}
}}`. Add it after $group stage.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your optimization request, I don't think there's a lot of room for improvement beyond the version that you already have. However, the following pipeline might be faster than your current solution because of the initial `$group` stage which should result in way less `$lookup`s. I am not sure how MongoDB will optimize all of that internally so you might want to profile the two versions against a real data set.

```
db.getCollection('something').aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '$city', // group by city
        "averageRating": { $push: "$_id" } // create array of all encountered "_id"s per "city" bucket - we use the target field name to avoid creation of superfluous fields which would need to be removed from the output later on
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'reviews',
        let: { "averageRating": "$averageRating" }, // create a variable called "$$ids" which will hold the previously created array of "_id"s
        pipeline: [{
            $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$store", "$$averageRating" ] } } // do the usual "joining"
        }, {
            $group: {
                "_id": null, // group all found items into the same single bucket
                "rating": { $avg: "$rating" }, // calculate the avg on a per "store" basis
            }
        }],
        as: 'averageRating' 
    }
}, {
    $sort: { "averageRating.rating": -1 }
}, {
    $limit: 5
}, { 
    $addFields: { // beautification of the output only, technically not needed - we do this as the last stage in order to only do it for the max. of 5 documents that we're interested in
        "averageRating": { // this is where we reuse the field we created in the first stage
            $arrayElemAt: [ "$averageRating.rating", 0 ] // pull the first element inside the array outside of the array
        }
    }
}])
```

In fact, the "initial `$group` stage" approach could also be used in conjunction with @Veerams solution like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '$city', // group by city
        "averageRating": { $push: "$_id" } // create array of all encountered "_id"s per "city" bucket - we use the target field name to avoid creation of superfluous fields which would need to be removed from the output later on
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'reviews',
        localField: 'averageRating',
        foreignField: 'store',
        as: 'averageRating'
    },
}, {
    $project: {
        "averageRating": {
            $avg: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$averageRating",
                    in: { $avg: "$$this.rating" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: { averageRating: -1 }
}, {
    $limit: 5
}])
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking a look. I'll compare the two.